# How to rotate a `datagridview` in C#

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have `datatable` that has 1 `row` and of course caption name `columns`,
now I want to show them vertically in a `datagridview`

for example the `datagridview` must have 2 `columns` that `rows` of one of them shows caption name and the other shows related values of `datatable`
I try to do that by this code but it shows an exception:

> {"There is no row at position 1."}

the code is:

```
public static void GetSelectedFeedsDetails(Form1 frm)
{
    string StrCon = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["FeedLibraryConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    OleDbConnection Connection = new OleDbConnection(StrCon);
    OleDbDataAdapter DataA = new OleDbDataAdapter("Select * from SelectedFeeds where ID=" + frm.SelectedFeedlistBox.SelectedValue, Connection);
    DataTable OldDTable = new DataTable();
    DataA.Fill(OldDTable);


    DataTable NewDTable = new DataTable();

    NewDTable.Columns.Add("Feild Name");

    for (int i = 0; i < OldDTable.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        NewDTable.Columns.Add();
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < OldDTable.Columns.Count; i++)
    {
        DataRow NewRow = NewDTable.NewRow();
        NewRow[0] = OldDTable.Columns[i].Caption;

        for(int j = 0; j < OldDTable.Columns.Count; j++)
        {
            NewRow[j + 1] = OldDTable.Rows[j][i];
            NewDTable.Rows.Add(NewRow);
        }
    }
    frm.dataGridView1.DataSource = NewDTable;
}
```

what should I do?

Comment: I cannot reproduce your error. But if you move `NewDTable.Rows.Add(NewRow);` outside of the inner loop and change the inner loop condition to `j < OldDTable.Rows.Count`, everything should look exactly as desired.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as OhBeWise said the answer is:

```
DataTable NewDTable = new DataTable();

NewDTable.Columns.Add("Field Name");

for (int i = 0; i < OldDTable.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    NewDTable.Columns.Add();
}

for (int i = 0; i < OldDTable.Columns.Count; i++)
{
    DataRow NewRow = NewDTable.NewRow();
    NewRow[0] = OldDTable.Columns[i].Caption;

    for (int j = 0; j < OldDTable.Rows.Count; j++)
    {
        NewRow[j + 1] = OldDTable.Rows[j][i];
    }

    NewDTable.Rows.Add(NewRow);
}
```